# Eclipselink @mapkey and @JoinFetch(JoinFetchType.OUTER) cannot co-exist?

Tags: java, orm, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

In Customer.java entity class, i had below code:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "customer", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@MapKey(name = "key")
@JoinFetch(JoinFetchType.OUTER)
private Map<String, CustomerSuppInfo> suppInfoMap....
```

find out that when i query the customer entity, the SQL generated by eclipselink didn't join fetch the CustomerSuppInfo map (it generated 1 SQL to select the customer table, and then another 1 SQL to select the supp_info table by id)
All i want is to just generate 1 SQL and select the whole customer related field, so that to minimize # of SQL generated / EJB call.

is these 2 annotation cannot be co-exist? 
i had try to find the JPA documentation, but seems no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

If the annotation "@JoinFetch(JoinFetchType.OUTER)" is not causing EclipseLink to join fetch the "suppInfoMap" for all queries on the owning Entity and you have not overridden this mapping using XML then this is a bug.  You should file an EclipseLink bug.  Alternatively you could create your query to join in the "suppInfoMap" directly using the "JOIN FETCH" JPQL keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Example of your Query

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.MapKey;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class Department {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department")
    @MapKey(name="name")
    private Map students;

```
public Department() {
    students = new HashMap<String, Student>();
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String deptName) {
    this.name = deptName;
}

public void addStudent(Student student) {
    if (!getStudents().containsKey(student.getName())) {
        getStudents().put(student.getName(), student);
        if (student.getDepartment() != null) {
            student.getDepartment().getStudents().remove(student.getName());
        }
        student.setDepartment(this);
    }
}

public Map<String,Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Department id: " + getId() + 
           ", name: " + getName();
}
```

}

File: Student.java

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Student {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;

```
@ManyToOne
private Department department;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


public Department getDepartment() {
    return department;
}

public void setDepartment(Department department) {
    this.department = department;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Student id: " + getId() + " name: " + getName() + 
           " with " + getDepartment();
}
```

}

File: Helper.java

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Helper {
  public static void checkData() throws Exception {
    Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:data/tutorial", "sa", "");
    Statement st = conn.createStatement();

```
ResultSet mrs = conn.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, null, new String[] { "TABLE" });
while (mrs.next()) {
  String tableName = mrs.getString(3);
  System.out.println("\n\n\n\nTable Name: "+ tableName);

  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from " + tableName);
  ResultSetMetaData metadata = rs.getMetaData();
  while (rs.next()) {
    System.out.println(" Row:");
    for (int i = 0; i < metadata.getColumnCount(); i++) {
      System.out.println("    Column Name: "+ metadata.getColumnLabel(i + 1)+ ",  ");
      System.out.println("    Column Type: "+ metadata.getColumnTypeName(i + 1)+ ":  ");
      Object value = rs.getObject(i + 1);
      System.out.println("    Column Value: "+value+"\n");
    }
  }
}
```

}
}

File: Main.java

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.Query;

public class Main {
  static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPAService");
  static EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception {
    em.getTransaction().begin();

```
Student student = new Student();
student.setName("Joe");
em.persist(student);

Department dept = new Department();
dept.addStudent(student);
em.persist(dept);

em.flush();






Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT e FROM Student e");
List<Student> list = (List<Student>) query.getResultList();
System.out.println(list);

query = em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Department d");
List<Department> dList = (List<Department>) query.getResultList();
System.out.println(dList);

em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();
emf.close();

Helper.checkData();
```

}
}

File: persistence.xml

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence" version="1.0">